# Error: Upgrade failed: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get configmaps)

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

When deploying an application using Kubernetes I get the following exception:

Error: Upgrade failed: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get configmaps)

Can someone tell me about which credentials is rancher complaining, applications credentials or helm and tiller credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like problem with Using [RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) or [RoleBinding and ClusterRoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding)

Here you can find one of the [examples](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-examples):

> Allow reading a ConfigMap named “my-config” (must be bound with a RoleBinding to limit to a single ConfigMap in a single namespace):

```
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  resourceNames: ["my-config"]
  verbs: ["get"]
```

Please follow similar [issues](https://forums.rancher.com/t/helm-error-error-the-server-has-asked-for-the-client-to-provide-credentials/13325) related to k8s authorization in rancher  and for [helm](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/ha/helm-init/troubleshooting/?#).

Hope this help.